# Refresh content of jQuery UI Tabs Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to reload the content of one Tab by clicking a button.

Here is the re-design of my problem in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NhTzt/

I don't know how to do that.

```
function clear(){
 $("tabs-1").empty(); 

 /* load new content */     
}
```

Here is the API from jQuery UI Tabs http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ I didn't find a function that can serve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: `tabs-1` is an ID, you should call `$("#tabs-1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
var i=0;
$(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});

$('#button').click(function(){
  i++;
  $("#tabs div:visible").empty(); 
  $("#tabs div:visible").append('<p>new content'+i+'</p>');                        
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhTzt/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change content use this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     $("#tabs-1").empty().append("<span>new html or text</span>");
});
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qpgy/)**. You can combine it with some ajax request for eg. to get completely new content.